# phonegap ios loading url

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm building a hybrid app on ios with phonegap.
when I run it the default file to show on the emulator screen is index.html from the www folder
the question is, can I load an external page on the start like "www.mysite.com/mobile" ?

I've tried to change the code of "AppDelegate.m"

from

```
   self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
   self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
```

to

```
   self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"";
   self.viewController.startPage = @"www.mysite.com/mobile";
```

but I got an error when I run it on the device saying :

ERROR: start page at 
"/wwww.mysite.com/mobile" was not found